# Find the directional derivative using $f(x,y,z)=xy+z^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find the directional derivative using $f(x,y,z)=xy+z^2$, at the point $(2,3,4)$  in the direction of a vector making an angle of $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ with grad $f(2,3,4)$.

PS - I am having trouble figuring out what the (unit) direction vector is. I am unable to make use of the given angle.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Which part of the problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out what the (unit) direction vector is. I am unable to make use of the given angle.

Comment: Before that, you know the vector grad f(2,3,4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline for the steps to solve the problem and you have to fill in details.

$1$- calculate grade $f$ (the first component is the partial derivative in respect to $x$ the second is the partial derivative in respect to $y$ and the last is in respect to $z$).

$2$- Plug in the point $(2,3,4)$ to find the grade at this particular point.

But we want to calculate the grade at the direction of a vector $v$ making angle of $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ with the grade at this point.. so we use the dot product to calculate this (Remember: this means we want the component of the grade at this direction which is found using dot product).

We consider the unit vector $u$ at this direction  of the vector $v$. and the angle of between them is known. So,

$3$- The directional derivative in the direction of $v$=  grade $f|_{(2,3,4)} cos(\frac{3\pi}{4})$. We have calculated the grade at step#$2$ so we are done, it's a matter of multiplying numbers now.

Remark: The norm of the unit vector in the direction of $v$ is $1$ so it doesn't appear in the dot product

The point of the problem is that:

The directional derivative of a scalar function $f$ in the direction of the vector $v$ is the dot product between the grade of $f$ at this point and the ***unit*** vector of $v$.

Here we know the direction as we have the angle between them (which is $\frac{3\pi}{4}$).

Sorry for being wordy! but my answer is no more than a trial to show you what is needed to solve it.